# How do I connect to a EAP-SIM authenticated network (namely FreeWifi_secure from Free Mobile)?

Tags: wi-fi, cyanogenmod, sim-card, motorola-milestone-2

I am running [CyanogenMod 10](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1827801) (based on Android 4.1.2) on my Motorola Milestone 2.
I just switched to the French mobile carrier Free Mobile. They offer access to their "FreeWifi_secure" wifi network in the plan. The authentication method is known as EAP-SIM ; it connects using information in the SIM card. However, this option is not given when you try to connect using the "Settings" app in Android.

So I tried to connect to the FreeWifi_secure wifi by following a method explained on [XDA-Developers.com](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1660397). It consists in adding the following lines to `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` :

```
network={
    ssid="FreeWifi_secure"
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP IEEE8021X
    eap=SIM
    priority=70
}
```

I managed to follow the instructions but still cannot connect to the wifi network. FreeWifi_secure is correctly displayed as a favorite network, however, when trying to connect, it never goes past the "Connecting…" step.

Do you know whether the Milestone 2 is hardwarewise compatible with EAP-SIM ? Or is the incompatibility due to a software limitation in CyanogenMod ? Have you personally managed to use the Free Mobile wifi network ?

Comment: It looks like Android in general doesn't support EAP-SIM and Free Mobile's wifi network, CNet France ran a story about this back in April, here [Free Mobile : bascule 3G / Free WiFi mais pas pour Android ?](http://www.cnetfrance.fr/news/free-mobile-bascule-3g-free-wifi-mais-pas-pour-android-39770930.htm) (also you seem to have mis-copied your XDA link, it's got a load of dots in the middle instead of the actual address)

Comment: So I contacted Motorola's customer support and they told me that none of their phones was compatible with EAP-SIM.

Comment: Thanks for pointing at my broken link. However EAP-SIM *is* compatible with some Android phones as shown here for instance : http://forum.freenews.fr/index.php/topic,80665.0.html